# How can I use browserify module for adapting xml2js node module for the browser?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, libxml2, browserify

I am learning nodejs with noodcook book 2nd edition.

At chapter 3, Sending serialized data from the client to the server,

I faced obstacle.

below is add_profile_server.js file

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var profiles = require('./profiles');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var index = fs.readFileSync('add_profile_index.html');
var clientXml2js = fs.readFileSync('./xml2js.js');

var routes, mimes = {
    js: "application/javascript",
    json: "application/json",
    xml: "application/xml"
};

function output(content, format, rootNode) {
    if (!format || format === 'json') {
        return JSON.stringify(content);
    }
    if (format === 'xml') {
        return (new xml2js.Builder({rootName: rootNode})).buildObject(content);
    }
}



routes = routes = {
    'profiles': function (format) {
        return output(Object.keys(profiles), format);
    },
    '/profile': function (format, basename) {
        return output(profiles[basename], format, basename);
    },
    'xml2js' : function(ext) {
        if (ext === 'js') { return clientXml2js; }
    }
};

function updateProfiles(profile, type, cb) {
    var name = Object.keys(profile).pop();
    profiles[name] = profile[name];
    cb(output(profiles[name], type, name));
}

function addProfile(request, cb) {
    var pD = ''; //post data
    request
    .on('data', function (chunk) { pD += chunk; })
    .on('end',function() {
        var contentType = request.headers['content-type'];
        if (contentType === 'application/json') {
            updateProfiles(JSON.parse(pD), 'json', cb);
        }
        if (contentType === 'application/xml') {
            xml2js.parseString(pD, {
                explicitRoot: false,
                explicitArray: false
            }, function(err, obj) {
                updateProfiles(obj, 'xml', cb);
            });
        }
    });
}


http.createServer(function (request, response) {
var dirname = path.dirname(request.url),
    extname = path.extname(request.url),
// Return the last portion of a path. (optional-extname: return only file name on mattached ext)
    basename = path.basename(request.url, extname);

console.log("URL: "+request.url);
console.log("dirname:"+dirname);
console.log("extname:"+extname);
console.log("basename:"+basename);
console.log("");


    extname = extname.replace('.', ''); //remove period

    if (request.method === 'POST') {
        addProfile(request, function(output) {
            response.end(output);
        });
    return;
    }
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", mimes[extname] ||'text/html');
// If the subroute exists in the routes object, we call the method stored at that namespace passing in basenameand extname
    if (routes.hasOwnProperty(dirname)) {
        response.end(routes[dirname](extname, basename));
        return;
    }
    if (routes.hasOwnProperty(basename)) {
        response.end(routes[basename](extname));
        return;
    }
    response.end(index);    
}).listen(8080);
```

and below is add_profile_index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            #frm, #raw {display:block; float:left; width:210px}
            #raw {height:150px; width:310px; margin-left:0.5em}
            #add {display:block; float:left; margin-left:1.5em}
            #add div {display:table-row}
            #add label {float:left; width:5.5em}
                 div button {float:right}
        </style>
        <title> INDEX </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="frm">
            Profile: <select id="profiles">
            <option> </option>
            </select>
            <br></br>

            Format:<select id="formats">
            <option value="json"> JSON </option>
            <option value="xml"> XML </option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <div id="output"></div>
        </form>
        <textarea id="raw"></textarea>

        <form id="add">
            <div><label>profile name</label><input name="profileName"> </input></div>
            <div><label>name</label><input name="name"></input></div>
            <div><label>irc</label><input name="irc"></input></div>
            <div><label>twitter</label><input name="twitter"></input></div>
            <div><label>github</label><input name="github"></input></div>
            <div><label>location</label><input name="location"></input></div>
            <div><label>description</label><input name="description"></input></div>
            <div><button>Add</button></div>
        </form>

        <script src="xml2js.js"></script>
    </body>

    <script>
        function load(done) {
            $.get('http://localhost:8080/profiles',

                function (profile_names) {
                    $.each(profile_names, function (i, pname) {
                        $('#profiles').append('<option>' + pname + '</option>');
                    });
                done && done();
                },
            'json');
        }
        load(); 
        $('#add').submit(function(e) {
            var output, obj = {}, format = $('#formats').val(), profileName;
            e.preventDefault();
            $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function(i, nameValPair) {
                obj[nameValPair.name] = nameValPair.value; //form an object
            });
            profileName = obj.profileName; 
            delete obj.profileName;

            obj = {_: obj}; 
            obj[profileName] = obj._;   
            delete obj._;

            output = (format === 'json') ? JSON.stringify(obj) :
             (new xml2js.Builder({rootName: profileName})).buildObject(obj);
            $.ajax({ 
                    type: 'POST', 
                    url: '/', data: output,
                    contentType: 'application/' + format, dataType: 'text',
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#raw').val(response);
                        $('#profiles').html('<option></option>');
                        load(function () {
                            $('#profiles').val(profileName);
                        });
                    }
            });
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

Before starting the server, We need to type below command

**npm -g install browserify**

**browserify node_modules/xml2js -s xml2js -o xml2js.js**

I think I follow the book straightly for building example code but

the above code is not working especially when dealing on xml format. I think the problem is browserify module.

I went through https://www.npmjs.org/package/browserify to understand browserify, but it is pretty hard for me to understand and use the module properly.

Can you let me know what is the problem???

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer myself.

The main problem was **browserify node_modules/xml2js -s xml2js -o xml2js.js**

It was not working.

So we need to adapt new browserify module.

First, made any javascript file(xml2jsM.js) including below code.
    'use strict';

```
var _ = require('xml2js');

var logUnderscoreVersion = function() {
  console.log(_.VERSION);
}

module.exports = logUnderscoreVersion;
```

and then install underscore module. ( npm install underscore )

and then make a bundle file. ( browserify xml2jsM.js > bundle.js )

and then include   on add_profile_index.html

(You can reference those steps on http://lincolnloop.com/blog/untangle-your-javascript-browserify/ )

If you have any question, let me know.

Thank you~

Comment: The above method worked for browser but I'm using systemjs and I can't figure out how to resolve the dependency(although everthing is there in the bundled file). For now I've added xml2js in window object there by globally accessible . It would be great if anyone suggested me how to use it in systemjs.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to fine some examples in here http://opennodes.arecord.us/md/xml2js.md see if the examples are helpful to you.

Have you try something like this?

Instead of

```
(new xml2js.Builder({rootName: profileName})).buildObject(obj);
```

Try:

```
var xml2js = require('xml2js');
var builder = new xml2js.Builder({rootName: profileName}));
builder.buildObject(obj);
```